# In Angularjs, can I $apply / render a single scope at a time?

Tags: performance, angularjs

I have a fairly complex app, with lots of different components that update frequently. For example, a clock.

Is it possible to call $apply / $digest on only a subsection of the page at once? I don't want to call every watcher on the page for every single clock tick, for example.

I know I can achieve this by bypassing $scope.$apply entirely, and just updating the clock elements manually in a directive. Is there any hope for me?

EDIT: Actually, it looks like MAYBE what I want is to dun $digest, starting on the scope I want to check, rather than $apply, since $apply kicks off the digest on $rootScope. Is this a valid way to do it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/C8aOswf46qx2GoD5uL9Y?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `$scope.$apply()` it also calls `$apply()` on all scopes that fall within that scope. If you want to call `$apply()` on a limited section of a page then that section needs to have it's own scope, which you can do by adding a controller to that section of the page. Then you can use that controller to update the scopes within that section of the page using `$scope.apply()` on your section controller.

-- Edit --
See comments below for additional details about the differences between $apply and $digest.

Also see:

- http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/SSj61VOBBSc

Comment: That's what I thought, but here's a plunker demo suggesting otherwise: http://plnkr.co/edit/C8aOswf46qx2GoD5uL9Y?p=preview

Comment: The demo may be causing some confusion between $apply and $digest. At the end of $apply() it will call $digest() on the $rootScope. Because the demo updates the value of $rootScope.foo, if $scope.$apply() is called then the $rootScope will also digest the changes made to the value $rootScope.foo.

Answer (score 0):

If your components are really decoupled, you could isolate those that generate frequent updates in their own angular app instance. They will have independent digest cycles.

Your apps can still communicate but there is a bit more overhead involved.

In order to have 2 apps, you have to manually start the applications (use `bootstrap` instead of `ng-app`).

See this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/K3bnACFi79g5Kh0kFS66?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, this is something we considered as well. It seems like we'd be giving up a ton of convenient functionality we'd have access to as part of a single app instance, though.

Comment: Can you list the most important functionality you've identified because I too am pondering on the idea of using individual apps. Thanks!

Comment: For example, aside from whatever overhead comes with having multiple apps, we lose the angularjs template cache (for components and such), we lose having a central place to decorate the built in $http stuff (for metrics, etc), we are responsible for writing our own communications layer to connect the apps, etc etc etc.